# Union query with left join : Group & Ordering Issues

Tags: sorting, union

I have finally figured out how to perform a somewhat successful UNION query with left joins! Yeah (snaps for me)..

Now, the problem I'm running into is that I can get it to Group them so that I only have one entry for each code...

```
SELECT vg.*, lh.*
FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg
INNER JOIN tbl_luchthaven lh
ON lh.luchthavenID = vg.vertrekluchthaven
UNION  
SELECT vg.*, lh.*  
FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg  
INNER JOIN tbl_luchthaven lh
ON lh.luchthavenID = vg.aankomstluchthaven
GROUP BY lh.luchthavencode;
```

I've tried grouping based on the luchthavencode, which is what i'm displaying. I've tired the luchthavenID...

Here is a sample of what I am trying to accomplish (note: I did not spend a lot of time reproducing the field names in my tables, I just used some shorthand, i will translate that later)

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve. This board won't let me post until I have at least 10 reputation.
http://globe-trekking.com/union_query_example.jpg

kind of pulling my hairs out on this... though i'm sure it's simple?

Any help would be great!

Regards,

Comment: Hi, May I know what you're really achieving for this? It's better if you can put some data

Comment: I have added an example of what I am trying to achieve... I have done this in MS Access but had to do a prep query. i am sure this is possible without a prep query in MySQL but just can't figure it out...

Comment: Hi, i presume gID = LID?

Comment: No. The LID is the value for either vertrek or aankomst.

Comment: May I know where's your desired output? sorry having a hard time trying to read the table names..

Comment: I wish to pull the vertrek & aankomst fields into a single column.. From here, take the code & name from the luchthaven table and display that information as just a single record.

As of now, I am getting something like what I want, but it is showing me 2 values for each airport.

see http://globe-trekking.com/vluchtgegevens/luchthavens.php for what I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it fits for you

```
SELECT
 Luchthaven.Luchthaven.luchthavencode as CODE,
 Luchthaven.luchthavennaam as NAME
FROM 
 Luchthaven , Vluchtgegens
WHERE
 Luchthaven.LID = Vluchtgegens.vertrek AND
 Luchthaven.LID = Vluchtgegens.aankomst AND
ORDER BY Luchthaven.luchthavennaam DESC
GROUP BY Luchthaven.luchthavennaam
```

Comment: No, that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: No, that is not what I am looking for.

The code errors out>

Also, I am looking to pull the codes from the tbl_vlucthgegevens fields, vertrekluchthaven and aankomstluchthaven; and display their corresponding codes and names, but not where they are both equal. 

So I believe it has to be a Union query, because they are two different fields, though from the same table.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it by using:

```
select *
from 
(
SELECT vg.vertrekluchthaven AS code
FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg
WHERE vg.vertrekdatum <=NOW()
UNION  
SELECT vg.aankomstluchthaven AS code
FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg  
WHERE vg.vertrekdatum <=NOW()
) vg
INNER JOIN tbl_luchthaven lh
ON  lh.luchthavenID = vg.code
Group by vg.code
Order by lh.luchthavencode;
```

Thanks for your help... sorry if my thought process was not very clear.